# Using Photoshop, how can I move non-contiguous areas of an image onto a separate layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have an image and want to "factor out" a new layer from the image.  I know I can select an area and use Control+J to create a new layer but I want to select multiple parts of the image that are not continuous.

For example, if I want to take the below image of a cookie and have the chips moved to another layer, how can I select just the chips using Photoshop?

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a mask. Once your mask is up to your liking (Hint: use quick mask mode, much faster) you can either cut to remove or copy to duplicate and then paste your clipboard to a new layer.

As an alternative, duplicate the layer you're trying to refactor and just mask off and delete the content you don't want/need.

Answer (score 3):

I would duplicate the layer. Twice. Then select color range of the chips, then make mask on one layer. The invert selection, make mask on other layer. Put the unmasked layer on the bottom, and use clone to fill in the holes where the chips were. 
Now you have two layers, one that has only chips showing, one that has only cookie.
You can paint the mask to trim up the cookies, blur it a bit for nicer edges.

Comment: We must have been typing at exactly the same time Bobbi. :P

Comment: That is a nice cartoon cookie. The drop shadows will give trouble using color-range. So make masks, set your brush to round and sharp, and paint the mask white over the chip parts. Remember to select the mask before you paint!

Answer (score 1):

Or, since there are nice clean limited colors and fixed line widths, select color range to get the inside of the chip, then expand selection until you get the outline too.